# If date equals today, add a badge. React JS and Ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, conditional-statements, ionic-react

Im trying to add a "New" badge `example: <IonBadge color="primary">New</IonBadge>` in the `<IonCardHeader>` if the `(job.createdAt)` equals "today".

How would you recommend I go about this?

The date as in, the current date, not a string.

Im using Ionic React v4.

Card Function below.

Thanks so much for your insights!!

```
function renderJobList(job) {
    return [{}].concat(job).map((job, i) =>
      i !== 0 ? (


            <LinkContainer key={job.jobId} to={`/jobinfo/${job.jobId}`}>
            <IonItemGroup>
            <IonCard>
              <IonCardHeader>
                <IonCardSubtitle><b>{(job.packageSelected)}</b></IonCardSubtitle>
                <IonCardTitle><h3>{(job.streetAddress)} {(job.city)} {(job.state)} {(job.zipCode)}</h3></IonCardTitle>
              </IonCardHeader>

              <IonCardContent>
                <p><b> Start Date: </b> {parseISO(job.startDate).toLocaleString()}</p>
               <p><b> Created At: </b> {new Date(job.createdAt).toLocaleString()}</p>
              </IonCardContent>
            </IonCard>
            </IonItemGroup>
            </LinkContainer>
```

Comment: "today" as string or "today" as current date?

Comment: @Stepan I apologize, I should have clarified. Date as in current date, not a string.

Comment: You can compare the two dates using `.toDateString()`. For example: `parseISO(job.createdAt).toDateString() == new Date().toDateString()`

Comment: Using toDateString will ensure that the time portion of the date is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this:

```
let today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
```

and then use:

```
<IonCardHeader>{job.createdAt == today ? (<IonBadge color="primary">New</IonBadge>) : null}</IonCardHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stepan ! So I implemented this but i completely forgot to mention that I have the Time included as well in ```job.createdAt```. Trying to figure out how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Date object and then match the date string

```
const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
const isToday = new Date(job.createdAt).toISOString().slice(0, 10) == today;
// implement your logic based on isToday boolean
```